# Frame Writing with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a code to run video  with 30 fps for 10 seconds and i have  to save the frames in that interval.for 10 seconds and for 30 fps we should have 30x10=300 frames in a folder.but i have the 70 frames in that folder. but i don't know why it happens.here is my code

```
import cv2
import time
timeout=time.time()+10
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,30)
f=1
while(True):
      ret,frame=cap.read()
      cv2.imshow('test',frame)
      fps=cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,30)
      print('fps',fps)
      cv2.imwrite('Data/'+str(f)+'.jpg')
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
     if time.time()>timeout:
        break  
     f=f+1
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have you tried smth like cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)?

Comment: ye sir....my camera gives 640x480  fps of 30 by default

Comment: defaults of opencv and camera can differ. does it work faster without cv2.imshow or with time.sleep() inside a loop?

Comment: i have  checked it now. it gives me 30 fps.but the problem remains there.

Comment: 30fps with cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)?

Comment: yes,and also i modified the above code.

Comment: 649x480 pixels at 3 bytes of RGB per pixel is 900kB per frame. And 30 fps for 10s is 300 frames. So you can likely store all 270MB in an array while you acquire and write it all to disk at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 fps is capture rate without writing operation of frames. In order to increase frames in your folder you need to capture frames while writing previous frame. You should use multithreading for this purpose. The working principle is as follows.

- While one thread capturing frames, another thread writes previous frame.